# Press call button, open a dialog then initiate intent to call on click yes option

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-tabs

i am trying to have user click my call button then open an alert dialog with 2 options (call and cancel buttons) i have tried to implement some code but throws exception. very vague i know but to keep it simple how do i achieve my goal using an alerdialog

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if ((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1)) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phones, container, false);

            //button decloration
            Button newPage = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.view3);
            newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) { Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:07**********"));




                    startActivity(callIntent);                }

            });
            return view;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in one method, and call that method as per you need.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new myOnDismissListener());

        alertDialog.setTitle("TITLE");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to call ?");
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                //PUT YOUR CALL PHONE CODE HERE

            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }

        });
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    class myOnDismissListener implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do i insert all of   //button decloration
            Button newPage = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.view3);
            newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) { Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:07**********"));




                    startActivity(callIntent);                }

            });
            return view;

        } where you state your call code here

Comment: just do button declarationin oncreate() and then implement onClickListener().  And in onClick() method, call one method like, callPhone(), implement callPhone(){} method and put my code there.

Comment: sorry im not getting this at all, think ive been at it too long lol

Comment: Do not consider BaseActivity, replace your Acivity name in replace with BaseActivity.